# Variable creation & regularizers inside tf.map_fn callable

Tags: tensorflow

The input tensor is of shape [batch, d1, d2]. I would like to create a neural net that takes a tensor of shape [d2] for each of the d1 elements.

```
weight_reg = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(0.01)
def _inner_nn(t):
  v = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.constant(0.0), ...)
  return tf.layers.dense(t, 10, kernel_regularizer=weight_reg)

inner_op = tf.map_fn(input_tensor, inner_nn)
return tf.reduce_mean(inner_op, axis=1)
```

I find two issues here:
1.

```
Initializer for variable v is from inside a control-flow construct, such as a loop or conditional. When creating a variable inside a loop or conditional, use a lambda as the initializer.
```

Not sure how to use a lambda as an initializer to handle this error.

2. When summing up regularization losses, it doesn't seem to allow using the regularizer from `_inner_nn`.

```
ValueError: Cannot use 'map/while/dense/kernel/Regularizer/l2_regularizer' as input to 'add' because 'map/while/dense/kernel/Regularizer/l2_regularizer' is in a while loop. See info log for more details.
```

Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do (or to work around / fix these issues)?